# Previously functioning 1-line Word AppleScript now throwing error

Tags: ms-word, applescript, keyboard-maestro

I have been using the following script in Keyboard Maestro to promote/demote paras in Word (for various reasons it works better than a straight custom-keyboard shortcut).

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    outline demote (paragraphs of selection)
end tell
```

(The parallel script uses `outline promote`.)

This was working fine for ages, including in the weeks since I upgraded to Mavericks.

Now, however, it fails, with an "Expected end of line but found identifier" error, with `demote` highlighted in ASE.

Comment: It seems to work in both ASE and Script Debugger in Mavericks. Have you tried copying and pasting from the code above into ASE and running it from there?

Comment: Thanks – yes, I have tried that, and it's producing the same error (highlighting "demote"). I'm not a heavy AppleScript user; could another dictionary be interfering, or something?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being at least I seem to have fixed the problem by changing the first line from

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
```

to

```
tell application "Word"
```

When run for the first time in either ASE or Keyboard Maestro, this script acquires syntax highlighting, **"Word" is automatically switched back to "Microsoft Word"**, and from then on (so far) it works.

If anybody can explain to me why that fixed it I would be very grateful.